# kenlm.Model' object has no attribute 'score' while running on google cloud ML

Tags: attributeerror, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine, kenlm

AttributeError: 'kenlm.Model' object has no attribute 'score'

```
>>> model = kenlm.Model('LM/en.europarl-nc.lm')
>>> model.score('This is a test')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'kenlm.Model' object has no attribute 'score'
```

Comment: Could you provide some details about how you're including kenlm as a dependency in your training code?

Comment: I have given kenlm dependency from pypi in  setup.py. I have used this  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypi-kenlm/0.1.20160618